# Proper way to pronounce and form the word for "The followers of Augusto Pinochet"

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

An article in this month's Monocle, discussing elections in Chile, referred to anti-Pinochetistas:

> The vote was attended by a throng of cheering anti-Pinochetistas.

I am wondering how the word should be pronounced and formed:

1. **Pinochetista** with a silent T, as one would pronounce Pinochet? (Pee-no-shay-*ee*-stah)
2. **Pinochetista** with an articulated T, avoiding an awkward diphthong? (Pee-no-shay-*tee*-stah)
3. **Pinochista**, formed like "Francista", the followers of Francisco Franco, by removing the last syllable "-et" and appending the suffix "ista": Pee-no-chee-stah

Answer (score 3):

His name is Pinochet [auˈɣusto pinoˈtʃet], - the t is silent in French but not in Spanish.

So I would suggest Peenotjetistas

Wikipedia: 
Spanish pronunciation: [pinoˈtʃet]; 
North American English: /piːnoʊˈtʃɛt/, 
Commonwealth English: /ˈpiːnoʊʃeɪ/). 
Pinochet pronounced his name with a silent t, but it is common for the /t/ to be pronounced by 
Spanish-speaking Chileans.

A Spanish colleague told me that pronouncing it in French is considered pretentious

Comment: Even if you do pronounce his name with no t, the derived form should surely have one, just as in ‘debut’ (no t) vs. ‘debutant’ (with t).

Comment: After speaking with some South Americans, they intuited that the last syllable of his name _might_ be dropped when appending the suffix. Thus, "pinochistas". I amended my question to also include the formation of the word.